# ggplot2 geom_ribbon from mgcv::gamm

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction

I'm trying to add a ribbon based on predictions from a gamm model, this seems a little harder than intended, as gamm is somewhat different from gam.

I first tried directly with geom_stat, but that will not work (and will not use my entire model, which also includes several other covariates)

```
library(tidyverse); library(mgcv)

dt = cbind(V1=scale(sample(1000)), 
    Age=rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 40, sd = 10), 
    ID=rep(seq(1:500),each=2) %>% as.data.frame()

# Works fine ----
dt %>% ggplot(aes(x=Age, y=V1)) + 
   stat_smooth(method="gam", formula= y~s(x,bs="cr")) 

# Fails horribly :P 
dt %>% ggplot(aes(x=Age, y=V1)) + 
    stat_smooth(method="gamm", formula= y~s(x,bs="cr"))

Maximum number of PQL iterations:  20   
iteration 1  
Warning message:  
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:  
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('gamm', 'list')"
```

I've tried using the predict function on the model$gamm, but I'm not sure how to use this, and how to make the CI ribbon

```
dt.model = gamm(V1 ~ s(Age, bs="cr") + s(ID, bs = 're'), data=dt, family="gaussian", discrete=T)

dt$pred = predict(dt.model$gam)

dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = V1)) +
   geom_line(aes(group=ID), alpha=.3) +
   geom_point(alpha=.2) +
   geom_smooth(aes(y=pred))
```

I recognise this is shitty example data because this is a stupid shape.
But I'd like to be able to add a ribbon with the CI along the line as predicted by the model.fit. And I'd prefer to do this in ggplot, particularly as I want a spagetti plot in the background.

Comment: @MarcoSandri sorry about that, copied an old test example. I have added it now. It's all completely arbitrary in this example. I'm terrible at data simulation :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `se.fit=TRUE` inside `predict`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)

dt <- cbind(V1=scale(sample(1000)), 
    Age=rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 40, sd = 10), 
    ID=rep(seq(1:500),each=2)) %>% as.data.frame()

dt.model <- gamm(V1 ~ s(Age, bs="cr") + s(ID, bs = "re"), 
           data=dt, family="gaussian", discrete=T)

pred <- predict(dt.model$gam, se.fit=T)

dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = V1)) +
   geom_line(aes(group=ID), alpha=.3) +
   geom_point(alpha=.2) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred$fit-1.96*pred$se.fit,
                   ymax=pred$fit+1.96*pred$se.fit), alpha=0.2, fill="red")+
   geom_line(aes(y=pred$fit), col="blue", lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! Such a small thing, great difference!

Comment: do you have any way to get the prediction from just one of the predictors? Say I wanted to plot each of the predictors curves separately, or just one of them?

    plot(dt.model$gam, shade = TRUE, shade.col = "red1")

Will promt you to rotate through all the different predictors, in this case two. Of which I am only interested in the first:

    plot(dt.model$gam, select=1, shade = TRUE, shade.col = "red1")

Any way to get predict JUST to predict with the first (or Xth ) predictor?

Running the above on actual models is not pretty

Comment: @AthanasiaMowinckel If I correctly understood  your question, you need partial dependence plots. Take a look at the `pdp` R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdp/pdp.pdf with special attention to `partial` function.

Comment: Yes, this looks like something I'd like, but are you getting the examples to work? I've been trying to run them and get 

> partial(boston.rf, pred.var = c("lstat", "rm"), grid.resolution = 40,  plot = TRUE, chull = TRUE, progress = "text")

Error: is.function(...f) is not TRUE

Comment: @AthanasiaMowinckel On my R 3.4.3, `partial(boston.rf, pred.var = c("lstat", "rm"), grid.resolution = 40, plot = TRUE, chull = TRUE, progress = "text")` works with no errors. I get the following image: https://imgur.com/a/aU6Ya

Comment: at @AthanasiaMowinckel, did you ever solve this problem?  I have the same weird is.function error as you

Comment: @Parseltongue I ended giving up the approach, and rather started using `predict`, or `broom::augment` with the new data argument, where you provide a data.frame with all the predictors of nonr-interest to your plot as constants, which then will predict on the remaining variables you have that are left varying in the data.